# Deny access to pages or nodes base from a database table

Tags: 7, nodes, users, hooks

I was modifying a 2fa module for restricting users to access other account's page (user/%/2fa) which is working.

```
function custom_2fa_menu() {
  $items['user/%/2fa'] = [
    'title'           => t('2FA Settings'),
    'type'            => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'file'            => 'inc/user.inc',
    'page callback'   => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'  => ['custom_2fa_settings_form', 1],
    'access callback' => 'custom_2fa_extra_settings_access',
    'access arguments' => [1]
  ];

  return $items;
}

function custom_2fa_extra_settings_access($account) {
  $uid = is_object($account) ? $account->uid : (int) $account;

  // Never allow access to view the anonymous user account.
  if ($uid) {
    // Admins can view all, users can view own profiles at all times.
    if ($GLOBALS['user']->uid == $uid || user_access('administer users')) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    elseif (user_access('access user profiles')) {
      // At this point, load the complete account object.
      if (!is_object($account)) {
        $account = user_load($uid);
      }
      return (is_object($account) && $account->status);
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

But is there a way to restrict user from access all the pages except (register, login, user change password, user/%/2fa) base from a database table's enabled column as well?

The db table `custom_2fa_settings` below:

```
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
| uid | secret                                                           | enabled |
+-----+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|  50 | TGP4DCVOGPCWBHYCW7MLR5EN3VZNNC2JXOYN5DXVKJK5BVMI5YV4O5HPJME |       1 |
|   1 | ODNYTJPL52JRXQYVKDTKI7FH3TWIXAFRCKYMCCUZB2DY4S5HPC7OG3DSINH |       0 |
|  32 | RUUKOVZIF3ECOPR33YNSZJBCANSTS6FMUZWHSXQZOLLZE6YCYS7KFIJ4LQV |       0 |
```